# Vue add class to target but remove from other instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm attempting to create a sortable table component in Vue and it's all working but I just wanted to add some little finishing touches, one thing I wanted was to add a class to the column that is currently being sorted and remove it from all other columns but I can't work out how to do the last part. I keep reading things saying that I shouldn't be trying to target DOM elements in Vue which makes me also think my use of `event.target.classList.add()` isn't correct either.

This is my method as it stands now:

```js
  methods: {
    sort_column (event, index) {
      if (this.sortAsc) {
        event.target.classList.add('sortable--down')
        this.sortAsc = false
        return this.tableData.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[index] < b[index]) return -1;
          if (a[index] > b[index]) return 1;
          return 0;
        })
      } else {
        event.target.classList.add('sortable--up')
        this.sortAsc = true
        return this.tableData.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[index] > b[index]) return -1;
          if (a[index] < b[index]) return 1;
          return 0;
        })
      }
    },
  }
```

and this is where it is called:

```html
  <th v-for="(item, index) in headings" :key="index" 
  @click="sort_column($event, index)"">
```

Back in the days of jQuery, I would just target the parent of the clicked element, find all of the columns and remove the class from it but if I can't (or shouldn't) target DOM elements in Vue then I'm at a loss for the right way to do this.

Comment: Hi, addinionally to this question, did you tried https://vuetifyjs.com/en/?
They have a really nice implementation for tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind would be assigning the class with Vue like this. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Store the index of the column that was sorted (in a variable named `idxSorted` for this example) and then do (tested):

```
<th :class="{ sorted: (index === idxSorted) }" v-for="(item, index) in headings" :key="index" @click="sort_column($event, index)"">
```

You can assign the `sortable--down` and `sortable--up` classes the same way with an additional check for `sortAsc`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, I had a feeling I'd need to end up doing something frustratingly simple that I just couldn't see :)